# Pagination in JQuery, Jersey table

Tags: java, pagination, jersey, jquery-jtable

I got most of my table implemented in JQuery, but I am having trouble on the pagination bit.

How would I request the pagination values (`jtableIndex` etc.) from my jersey REST? I tried using `HttpServletRequest` but it doesn't work (variable not found).

Any Help would be appreciated. Or Any help on how to do pagination or infinite scrolling on table (JQuery plugin) would be helpful!

Comment: Do you mean [tag:jquery-jtable]? How is [tag:swing] relevant?

Comment: yes jquery-jtable, swing must have been an accident